# Edit data from import CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

Daily I receive a couple of CSV files to import into the database.

Currently some columns have `/r/n` within a piece of text. I do not want to loop all the lines because some files have more than 250k lines, this will take ages.

**Question:**

Is there any PHP function to `str_replace` ALL (for example: `/r/n` with `"`) given input for the whole file, instead of looping each line for line?

```
$csv = str_replace("\r\n", "", $csv);
$csv = str_replace("\r", "", $csv);
$csv = str_replace("\n", "", $csv);
```

Comment: The code you posted, have you tried it?

Comment: 250k lines is very small, looping through them all would take a fraction of a second. However str_replace takes an array, is it not working?

Comment: @Andreas Yea, tested it. However the $csv is the whole output from the uploaded CSV.

Comment: As far as I know it should work, that's why I asked. It shouldn't take more than a few seconds at most

Comment: @viion Perhaps I need to check if it takes to long indeed. Be right back!

Comment: @Andreas, ok! Do I need to read line by line (foreach $key => $value), or is the whole output available in one go?

Comment: I think the proper way to do it is that you post **all your code** and we correct it. Having this guessing game is quite hard.

Comment: Used a composer: https://packagist.org/packages/parsecsv/php-parsecsv. This one works. See my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used composer, which works: https://packagist.org/packages/parsecsv/php-parsecsv.

**Result:**
It will keep the `/r/n` and any other new lines. It will keep the value instead of splitting it into a new key.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the begining of the php file; you can increase the execution time even more depends on the size of csv

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

**coding**

```
    /*************starts****************/
    $file    = 'yourfile.csv';
    $search  = '\r\n';
    $replace = '';

    $str = file_get_contents($file);
    $str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
    file_put_contents($file, $str);
    /*************ends****************/
```

retrieve file content and do search and replace